# Подсчитать количество сравнений и пересылок в merge sort

Tags: c++, сортировка

Помогите правильно посчитать количество пересылок и сравнений.
Сомневаюсь в том что у меня правильно это

С - сравнений
М - пересылок

```
void merge(int *array, int first, int mid, int last)
{

    int *L = new int[mid - first + 1], *R = new int[last - mid];

    // формируем 2 подмассива
    for (int i = 0; i < (mid - first + 1); i++)
    {
        L[i] = array[first + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (last - mid); j++)
    {
        R[j] = array[mid + j + 1];
    }
    // из двух неотсортированнных делаем отсортированный массив
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = first;
    for (; (i < (mid - first + 1)) && (j < (last - mid)); k++)
    {
        C++;
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            array[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            M++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            M++;
        }
    }
    // если какой-то из массивов закончился раньше, а в другом остались еще элементы
    // то нужно все оставшиеся добавить в финальный массив
    for (; i < (mid - first + 1); i++, k++)
    {
        array[k] = L[i];
    }
    for (; j < (last - mid); j++, k++)
    {
        array[k] = R[j];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int first, int last)
{
    M = 0, C = 0;
    C++;
    if (first < last)
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, first, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid + 1, last);

        merge(array, first, mid, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Сомневаюсь в том что у меня правильно это* Сомневаетесь? Пройдите по всем операторам, и для каждого сформулируйте "это не сравнение/пересылка потому что ...". Где не сможете - ставьте соотв. инкремент.

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но в таком алгоритме под `R[]` можно место не выделять, сравнивать сразу с элемнтами правой части `array[]`. При таком подходе число пересылок сразу сократится на величину `last - mid`